# Log to both Xcode console and file

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm trying to get my logs to both Xcode console and a file with **Swift**. Solutions I found are either console or redirect to file only.

How can I get the log goes to both?

Note: Some logs are from other 3rd libraries and frameworks in my app, not just Swift's `print()`. So using macro or logging framework like CocoaLumberjack on the app won't help.

e.g. This will redirect all the log in the console to file when called, the console then becomes empty

```
  func logToFile() {
    var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
    let fileName = "app_log.txt"
    let logFilePath = (documentsDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

    freopen(logFilePath.cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii)!, "a+", stderr)
    freopen(logFilePath.cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii)!, "a+", stdin)
    freopen(logFilePath.cString(using: String.Encoding.ascii)!, "a+", stdout)
  }
```

Comment: If running the created binary through the Terminal, you could get the logs in the Terminal and in a file with `./binaryFile | tee output.log`

Answer (score 0):

I have extended your method a bit, now you would write a given string to an output file and also log it to the console.

I like to have another functions, which takes care of the given string, to use Parameters like

```
__FILE__ - String - The name of the file in which it appears.
__LINE__ - Int - The line number on which it appears.
__COLUMN__ - Int - The column number in which it begins.
__FUNCTION__ - String - The name of the declaration in which it appears.
```

Your extended method could now look like the following.

```
func logToFile(message: String) -> Void {
        var paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
        let documentsDirectory = paths[0]
        let fileName = "app_log.txt"
        let logFilePath = (documentsDirectory as NSString).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

        let fileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: logFilePath)
        var error:NSError?

        // simply create the file, here you could add first line or something
        // just make sure it exists
        if (!FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: logFilePath)) {
            let data = new Data();
            do {
                try data.write(to:fileUrl , options: .atomic)
            } catch {
                println("Can't create file \(error)")
            }
        }

        // start writing
        if let fileHandle = NSFileHandle(forWritingToURL: fileurl, error: &error) {

            let data = message.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.writeData(data)
            fileHandle.closeFile()
        }
        else {

        }

        // Now also print the result to console
        print(message)
    }
```

Comment: this mean I need to have control of the **message** in the first place, which I don't. Some logs are printed out by **NSLog**, or **print**, etc., inside of libraries I use.